# Handling platform-dependent behavior using #ifdefs in source files?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am developing software that will run on multiple platforms. I provide a general header file that includes all public API functions. The actual source files will contain very different code depending on the platform it is compiled for.

I could handle all platforms in the same .cpp-file, but I feel like that will get messy really really fast.

The next idea was, to have a source-file per platform, surrounded by #ifdefs that contains the platform specific code. I feel like this is a much cleaner way, because the wrong code basically doesn't even exist on the wrong platform. I am obviously not looking for the BEST way because that's very subjective.

1. Is this an acceptable way of handling platform-dependent code or am
   I committing a major mistake that I am missing?
2. Would you find code like this in medium to high quality code-bases?
3. Are there any major drawbacks to this method?

**Window.h:**

```
#pragma once
class Window
{
    public:
        void Create();
};
```

**Window_Win32.cpp:**

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include "Window.h"

void Window::Create()
{
    // Win32 specific
}
#endif
```

**Window_Linux.cpp:**

```
#ifdef LINUX
#include "Window.h"

void Window::Create()
{
    // Linux specific
}
#endif
```

Comment: Your question is too broad and primarily opinion based. But most people prefer to use the _pimpl idiom_ to realize that rather than creating a `#ifdef` unreadable hell of code.

Comment: True story. A company I worked for had a huge code base that ran on Solaris (stop laughing). They contracted Tata Corp our of India to port it to multi-platform (Solaris, AIX, AS/400, OS/390, HPUX). As god as my witness, their "soluton" as they added each platform was to copy/paste one source file at a time into *itself*, surround the entire past with `#ifdef PLATFORM_X`, and proceed to compile+fix, compile+fix, etc, until the thing compiled. Then moved on to the next source. Imagine that *five times over per source file*. I'm not a violent man, but I considered it after that.

Comment: @WhozCraig WoW. I'm still trying to close my mouth.

Comment: @Ripi2 Yeah, right? You find *a* bug, and you get to fix it in *minimal* 5x places in the source file it resides. And forget about refactoring. Ultimately, it cost over a million dollars in contract fees and we ended up throwing the entire thing out and writing a full-POSIX implementation (which worked on *every* platform, with a tiny number of platform-dependent code locations, nearly all of them dealing with dynamic module loading). We ended up with two source bases. Windows, and *everything else*. The everything-else was Solid with a capital-S. Fun project, but man what a start.

Comment: I prefer to put the platform specific implementation in its own source file and only include it in that platform's project/makefile/whatever. If you're not able to do that for whatever reason then using ifdef to exclude the contents of the file works too. We try very hard to not have platform specific headers unless they are only included by platform specific source files, other than a global configuration header.

Answer (score 1):

Using zillions of #ifdef to use the proper platform is a nightmare. But it's a way, and some famous code out there is done that way.

I prefer having different .h/.cpp for each platform, and also some .cpp for common code to all platforms.

The .h header should include the common objects/functions and include (via #ifdefs) the specific platform header (which has only objects/functions for that platform).

With this approach, you need different configuration/makefile/whatever build files for each platform.